# Get Android Internal Storage Files or Folder with PHP

Tags: php, android, http

I've tried so hard to find out the way to get files and folders in my android internal storage device but it doesn't work. I had change my android become a local server, it doesn't work too.

I'm insipired from Xender app in my android that can show my files and folders in my internal storage. How to read my internal storage using PHP languages ?

Comment: You have php running on your Android device? Why?

Comment: Yes, I use local server in my Android device. But my local server only can access certain path, it can't access out of the path. Ex : my local server only can access this path and the folders inside  mnt/sdcard/htdocs, it can't access mnt/sdcard.

Comment: You have not mentioned php in your answer. How is that possible? Php is not your server i think. With server you will mean a webserver?